# Is there a way I can do this to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have two arrays

```
$array1[0]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>100,"intr"=>50,"date"=>"2017-05-13");
$array1[1]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>100,"intr"=>50,"date"=>"2017-05-20");

$array2[0]=array("account"=>002,"others"=>30,"date"=>"2017-05-13");
$array2[0]=array("account"=>002,"others"=>20,"date"=>"2017-05-13");
$array2[1]=array("account"=>002,"others"=>30,"date"=>"2017-05-20");
$array2[2]=array("account"=>002,"others"=>20,"date"=>"2017-05-20");
```

I wanted to combine these 2 arrays into just one like this

```
$array3[0]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>100,"intr"=>50,"date"=>"2017-05-13","others"=>30);
$array3[1]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>'',"intr"=>'',"date"=>"2017-05-13","others"=>20);
$array3[3]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>100,"intr"=>50,"date"=>"2017-05-20","others"=>30);
$array3[4]=array("account"=>002,"prin"=>'',"intr"=>'',"date"=>"2017-05-20","others"=>20);
```

I am trying array_merge but it does not give me the result I wanted.
any inputs will be of great help. Thank you

Comment: Use array_merge() function of php

Comment: have you tried `array_merge_recursive()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php ?

Comment: how can you array2 has two 0 index

Comment: @SaurabhParekh He already mentioned that he are facing issues with array_merge then why are you referring to same again?

Comment: It's unclear to me which arrays you want to merge. Could you be more specific? Is it based on the values of "account" and "date"?

Comment: @Edwin Thank you but both array_merge_recursive  and array_merge give me the same result

Comment: @user3409662 , yes I want it to merge based on the values of account and date.

Comment: @KrisRoofe my bad Sorry some typo

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you..

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){
 if(isset($array1[$key])){
  array_merge($array1[$key],$array2[$key]);
 }
 else{
  $tempArray = array("account"=>'',"prin"=>'',"intr"=>'',"date"=>'');
  array_merge($array1[$key],$tempArray);
  array_merge($array1[$key],$array2[$key]);
 }
}

print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Thank you Zaheer, it seems to give me the same result as raw array_merge

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 loops and [the array_merge() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
foreach($array1 as $item1)
{
    foreach($array2 as $item2)
    {
        if($item1['account'] == $item2['account'] && $item1['date'] == $item2['date'])
        {
            $array3[] = array_merge($item1, $item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since your arrays have string keys (as opposed to numeric keys), you could replace:

```
$array3[] = array_merge($item1, $item2);
```

By:

```
$array3[] = $item1 + $item2;
```

And it would work, too.

---

Example input:

```
$array1[0] = array('account' => '000', 'date' => '2017-04-30', 'prin' => 100, 'intr' => 50);
$array1[1] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-01', 'prin' => 101, 'intr' => 51);
$array1[2] = array('account' => '002', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'prin' => 102, 'intr' => 52);

$array2[0] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-01', 'others' => 31); // Will match $array1[1]
$array2[1] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-01', 'others' => 21); // Will match $array1[1]
$array2[2] = array('account' => '002', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'others' => 32); // Will match $array1[2]
$array2[3] = array('account' => '002', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'others' => 22); // Will match $array1[2]
$array2[4] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '1999-12-31', 'others' => 11); // Won't match anything in $array1, because of the date
$array2[5] = array('account' => '999', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'others' => 99); // Won't match anything in $array1, because of the account
$array2[6] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'others' => 1); // Won't match $array1[1], because of the date, nor $array1[2] because of the account
```

Corresponding output:

```
$array3[0] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-01', 'prin' => 101, 'intr' => 51, 'others' => 31);
$array3[1] = array('account' => '001', 'date' => '2017-05-01', 'prin' => 101, 'intr' => 51, 'others' => 21);
$array3[2] = array('account' => '002', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'prin' => 102, 'intr' => 52, 'others' => 32);
$array3[3] = array('account' => '002', 'date' => '2017-05-02', 'prin' => 102, 'intr' => 52, 'others' => 22);
```

---

Note: I don't know where your data comes from, but if it comes from a database, you'd be better off using a `JOIN` in an SQL query.